# Why do I get this error relating to Mongoose Object not being a function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am creating this ecommerce application using MERN Stack, and I am in the process of creating an authentication for a user, and I am using JWT, I have built a login API endpoint, but I do not want to store the token in local storage, so I created a cookie and store the token there. When I test the login endpoint using postman, I get this error: "user.getJwtToken is not a function". I have pasted my code below, I don't know where I am making a mistake...

```
Model: User.js

import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import validator from 'validator';
import bcrypt from 'bcryptjs';
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Please enter your name'],
    maxlength: [30, 'Name can not exceed 30 characters']
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Please enter your email'],
    unique: true,
    validate: [validator.isEmail, 'Please enter a valid email address']
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Please enter your password'],
    minlength: [6, 'Password must be longer than 6 characters'],
    select: false
  },
  avatar: {
    public_id: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    url: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }
  },
  role: {
    type: String,
    default: 'user'
  },
  resetPasswordToken: String,
  resetPasswordExpire: Date
}, {
  timestamps: true
})

userSchema.pre('save', async function(next){
  if (!this.isModified('password')){
    next()
  }

  this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, 10)
}) 

userSchema.methods.matchPassword = async function(enteredPassword){
  return await bcrypt.compare(enteredPassword, this.password);
}

userSchema.methods.getJwtToken = function(){
  return jwt.sign({ id: this._id}, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
    expiresIn: process.env.JWT_EXPIRES_TIME
  })
}

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

export default User;
```

```
jwtToken.js

const sendToken = (res, statusCode, user) => {
  const token = user.getJwtToken();

  const options = {
    expires: new Date(
      Date.now() + process.env.COOKIE_EXPIRES_TIME * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
    ),
    httpOnly: true
  }

  res.status(statusCode).cookie('token', token, options).json({
    success: true,
    token,
    user
  })
}

export default sendToken;
```

```
User controller: authController.js

import User from '../models/User.js';
import asyncHandler from 'express-async-handler';
import sendToken from '../utils/jwtToken.js';

export const registerUser = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  const { name, email, password } = req.body;
  const userExists = await User.findOne({ email });

  if(userExists){
    res.status(400);
    throw new Error('User already exists');
  }

  const user = await User.create({
    name, 
    email, 
    password,
    avatar: {
      public_id: 'users/ejoka_sxbax2',
      url: 'https://res.cloudinary.com/ejoka/image/upload/v1638139726/users/ejoka_sxbax2.jpg'
    }
  });

  sendToken(user, 200, res)

})

// Login User /api/v1/login

export const loginUser = asyncHandler( async(req, res, next) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;

  if(!email || !password){
    res.status(400);
    throw new Error('Please enter email and password')
  }

  const user = await User.findOne({email}).select('+password');

  if(!user){
    res.status(401);
    throw new Error('Invalid email or password')
  }

  const isPasswordMatched = await user.matchPassword(password)

  if(!isPasswordMatched){
    res.status(401);
    throw new Error('Invalid email or password');
  }

  sendToken(user, 200, res);

})
```

```
Route: auth.js

import express from 'express';
import { loginUser, registerUser } from '../controllers/authControllers.js';

const router = express.Router();

router.post('/register', registerUser);
router.post('/login', loginUser);

export default router;
```

Comment: Can you post the error message?

Comment: @LucaDeAcha here is the error message: 
`
{
    "errMessage": "user.getJwtToken is not a function"
}
`

Comment: Looks like a typo: you appear to be calling the `sendToken` function with the arguments reversed.

Comment: @Joe Thank you so much, I was not seeing that!!!